# Retrofit handle success and error responses

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to connect to a REST server and I need to handle success responses and error responses. I based on [this sample](https://github.com/nisostech/RetrofitSample) to build my client.

For example, on get token method, server successful response has the following structure:

```
{"status":0, "result":"7f4e879d1f64b10b5719a5b0ab6c7419"}
```

And failure response is:

```
{"status":-1, "result":"Password is not valid"}
```

My problem is that app treats error responses as success. My codes are:

-Rest api methods interface:

```
public interface Restapi {
    @GET("/?method=get_token")
    void login(@Query("login") String login, @Query("password") String password, RestCallback<LoginResponse> callback);
}
```

-Model login response:

```
public class LoginResponse {
    //With @SerializedName("status") neither working 
    public int status;
    public String result;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

-Model error response:

```
public class RestError {
    public int status;
    public String message;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

-Rest callback:

```
public abstract class RestCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {
    public abstract void failure(RestError restError);

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        RestError restError = (RestError) error.getBodyAs(RestError.class);
        if (restError != null)
            failure(restError);
        else {
            failure(new RestError(-1, error.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

-Client class:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static Restapi REST_CLIENT;

    static {
        setupRestClient();
    }

    public static Restapi get() {
        return REST_CLIENT;
    }

    private static void setupRestClient() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(Constants.getEndpoint())
                .build();

        REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(Restapi.class);
    }
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: What's the response code from the server? Also, wrap `error.getBodyAs` in a `try catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not your Android code fault and retrofit is doing their job.  The reason why you are getting success callback for error case is your server is returning successful status code (200 - 299).

In this case, failure callback will be called only in case of network connection error or server is offline.

Comment: Server returns HTTP 200 although response is not correct. Thus, is problem of API design. Thanks Emma and @tibo